# More efficient approach to recoding a variable than mutate(ifelse)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to recode variables, but I suspect there is a more efficient solution than nested `if` statements. For example, is there a way to change the name of the column content without the `ifelse` combined with `mutate`.

If we have:

```
col
F
M
```

I want to change the values as shown:

```
col
1
0
```

I have tried using `mutate`:

```
mutate(col = ifelse(col == F, 1, 0))
```

Is there some other efficient way? For example when we have a col with multiple variants, using `ifelse` will be tiring.

Comment: See `help("case_when")`

Comment: Review: The question lacks some tags, eg what language is used, and maybe some more helpful tags. Adding the source code (preformatted) for your results is OK IMO.

Comment: @H.Hasenack it has the `r` tag indicating what language is used: R

Comment: @duckmayr - sorry I overlooked that. upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, which I personally prefer to approach with `dplyr::recode`:

Imagine you had a data.frame named `data`:

```
data <- data.frame(col = LETTERS[c(1:5,1:2)])
data
#  col
#1   A
#2   B
#3   C
#4   D
#5   E
#6   A
#7   B
```

You can use `recode` with a list of `value = replacement` pairs:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(col = recode(col, "A" = 1, "B" = 2,
                      "C" = 3, "D" = 4, "E" = 5))
#  col
#1   1
#2   2
#3   3
#4   4
#5   5
#6   1
#7   2
```

If there is a pattern to your replacements, you can get fancy with a named vector of replacements and `!!!`:

```
my.replacements <- setNames(1:5,LETTERS[1:5])
my.replacements
#A B C D E 
#1 2 3 4 5 

data %>% 
  mutate(col = recode(col, !!!my.replacements))
#  col
#1   1
#2   2
#3   3
#4   4
#5   5
#6   1
#7   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

- `match`

```
within(df, col <- match(col, c("M", "F")) - 1)
```

- `factor`

```
within(df, col <- as.integer(factor(col, levels = c("M", "F"))) - 1)
```

- `==`

```
within(df, col <- c(0, 1)[1 + (col == "F")])
```